# How to avoid overflow in expression (A - B * C) / D?

Tags: c++, overflow, integer-overflow

I need to compute an expression that looks like: `(A - B * C) / D`, where their types are: `signed long long int A, B, C, D;` Each number can be really big (not overflowing its type). While B * C could cause overflow, at same time expression `(A - B * C) / D` would fit in. How can I compute it correctly?

For example: In the equation `(Ax + By = C)`, assuming A * x is overflowing, but `y = (C - A * x) / B` could fit in. No need to use BigInteger or double data type.

Comment: Do you really intent to do the division in the integer type? That won't necessarily give a solution to the shown equation.

Comment: Do your division first

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, output must be an integer. Couldn't be there any solution using gcd?

Comment: @Taekahn How can you make the integer division correctly?

Comment: @AhmadAbdulRahman define “correct” are you saying you’re worried about losing precision from integer division? That’s a different question already answered on SO.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use two `long long int`s to hold intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the equation to do the division first while accounting for the remainders:

Assume / is integer division and everything is infinite precision:

```
x == x / y * y + x % y

(A - B * C) / D
((A/D * D + (A%D)) - (B/D * D + (B%D)) * (C/D * D + (C%D))) / D
(A/D * D - B/D * D * C/D * D - (B/D * D * (C%D) + (B%D) * C/D * D) + (A%D) - (B%D) * (C%D)) / D
(A/D * D - B/D * D * C/D * D) / D - (B/D * D * (C%D) + (B%D) * C/D * D) / D + ((A%D) - (B%D) * (C%D)) / D
(A/D - B/D * C/D * D) - (B/D * (C%D) + (B%D) * C/D) + ((A%D) - (B%D) * (C%D)) / D
A/D - B/D * C - B/D * (C%D) - (B%D) * C/D) + ((A%D) - (B%D) * (C%D)) / D
```

Assuming D is not too small and not too big then `x / D` and `x % D` are small and we can do this:

```
using T = signed long long int;

T compute(T a, T b, T c, T d) {
    T a1 = a / d, a2 = a % d;
    T b1 = b / d, b2 = b % d;
    T c1 = c / d, c2 = c % d;
    T m1 = b1 * c, m2 = b1 * c2, m3 = b2 * c1, m4 = b2 * c2;
    T s1 = a1 - m1 - m2 - m3, s2 = a2 - m4;
    return s1 + s2 / d;
}
```

The critical part is the multiplication for m1 through m4. The range of numbers b and c that overflow while the result should have fit is rather small I believe.

Comment: I have no idea and it will never cover all cases. This really should use (2N+1) bits to compute N bit inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change the order of the operations so it will look like:
A/D - (B/D)*C
The result should remain the same.

Comment: mathematically correct ,but (computer-)computationally VERY wrong !

Comment: @engf-010 Unless if (B/D)*C overflows too, what makes it wrong?

Comment: @fflores `A=2,B=1,C=1,D=2`, `(2 - 1*1)/2 = 0`, `2/2 - (1/2)*1 = 1` , `0 != 1`

Comment: Many (subtile) things. Too many to specify in a comment. But (A/D) may be 0 (needs possible correction) (B/D) may be 0 while (C/D) may not ,thus the division /and multiplication must be done by the max(B,C) and min( B,C). and there are other issues.
This requires a well thought of algorithm instead of a simple formula.

Comment: @eerorika Can you give an example where everything divides nicely in the original but still gives a different result?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Define "divides nicely"

Comment: @eerorika x/y where x is a multiple of y. So this should be a case where (a-b*c) is divisible by d.

Comment: Only one division really need take place. That is to say `((A-B)/D) * C`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `gcd` lets try that as alternative answer:

```
using T = signed long long int;

T gcd(T a, T b);
T compute(T a, T b, T c, T d) {
    // use gcd for (b * c) / d
    T db = gcd(b, d);
    T dc = gcd(c, d / db);
    T dm = db * dc;
    
    // use gcd on a for (a - b*c) / dm
    T da = gcd(a, dm);
    
    // split da for use on (b * c) / da
    db = gcd(b, da);
    dc = da / db;
    T dr = d / da;
    
    return ((a / da) - (b / db) * (c / dc)) / dr;
}
```

Only works if d has enough factors in common with a, b and c.